# Spring org.xml.sax.SAXParseException Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, spring

I am getting this exception below which mite be due to incorrect xsd that i am using please advise how to  overcome from this

below is the xsd declartions that i am using in my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

and below are the jars that i am using in my classpath

```
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/crimson.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jaxp.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jcert.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jms.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jndi.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jnet.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jsse.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/jta-spec1_0_1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibcrypt.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjms.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjmsadmin.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibjmsapps.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibrvj.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Release12/lib/thirdparty/tibco-ems/4.2.0/tibrvjms.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring-jms.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/commons-lang-2.6.jar/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/spring.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/spring-beans-2.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/spring-context-2.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/tibco/spring-core-2.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/org-apache-commons-logging.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-event-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-feed-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-file-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ftp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-groovy-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-http-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-httpinvoker-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ip-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jdbc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jms-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-jmx-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-mail-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-rmi-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-security-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-sftp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-stream-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-test-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-twitter-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-ws-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-xml-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/abcsaral/sprintintegrationn/spring integration/spring integration/spring-integration-xmpp-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/xerces.jar/xerces.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/xercesImpl.jar/xercesImpl.jar"/>
```

the exception that i am getting below is

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from class path resource [jms-spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 120; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 120; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: See `jms-spring-context.xml` line 11

Comment: Thanks Jens still not able to grasp please

Answer (score 0):

You are using spring beans 2.0.4.jar but reference the spring 3 xsd. That do not work.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

remove the version from the xsd location and it should work.

Also you should upgrade to a newer spring version.